# how to translate vue-i18n in compile-time with laravel-mix?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using `tightenco/jigsaw` to generate static HTML, I have a couple of Vue app, which is compiled by `laravel-mix`. I want to generate HTML for the different languages I'm able to translate the `blade` templates but for the `Vue` part I don't want to load the translations in runtime. My plan is to interact with the `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` on the compiler method, I tried these approaches but none of them are working.

```js
// addon.js
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

class CustomVue {
  webpackRules() {
    return {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: "vue-loader",
          options: {
            compiler: require("vue-template-compiler"),
            compile: function (template, options) {
              console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++");
              console.log(template);
              console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++");
              // Modify the template code here
              return template;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}

mix.extend("translatedVue", new CustomVue());
```

and

```js
// webpack.mix.js
mix
  .jigsaw()
  .translatedVue()
  .js("source/_assets/js/main.js", "js")
  .sass("source/_assets/scss/main.scss", "css")
  .sass("source/_assets/scss/cf-errors/main.scss", "css/cf-errors/")
```

With the above approach, nothing is logging in to the console. I also tried like this

```js
const customDirective = () => {
  return {
    name: "v-html",
    postTransformNode(el) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  };
};

mix.config.vue = {
  compilerOptions: {
    // add the custom directive to the list of plugins
    plugins: [customDirective()]
  }
};
```

To see if it's logging something, but no luck.
How can I interact with the template `SFC` before getting compiled?